# Android Application Single Instance

Tags: android

I have one problem in notification click event.

for example there is a four activity in application A,B,C,D.

Currently Activity B is open and i get notification ,when i click on notification i want to open activity D. and its its working fine but problem is when i click back button from actvity D, its open activity B.
I tried Intent.**FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** ,  Intent.**FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY**  ,Intent.**FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP** etc but still unsuccessful finish all intent.

please help me ,Thank you in advance.....

Comment: The problem is not clear, what would you like to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution, add flag in new Intent Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, I think you have to override the **back button**, in order to give it a custom behaviour. Something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // Go to previous activity, or some other place
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: i don't know what you understand but should you tell me what i do in below if condition?     
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // Go to previous activity, or some other place
    }
Actually i want to kill application on back button in Activity D where we come from notification click event..

Comment: Hello Thanks for help but i found the solution Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY

Comment: No problem. :) Just write that as an answer and mark it as the solution, for anyone that is looking for a similar problem.